# CRUD over two different collections of POCOs

Tags: c#, generics, collections, delegates, compare

I have an interesting question, one I'm having difficulty searching for an answer on.

I have two IEnumerable collections of objects.  The underlying objects are completely separate, BUT I can identify a shared key that should match.  The collections are important, in that my "left" object is the "system of record", and the "right" object is representing a system I need to ensure matches the system of record.

Once they are matched, I need to perform CRUD operations on one side to bring the right side in line with the left side.  For example, it would create a new item on the right side if one didn't exist, or update values, or delete if the item was missing on the left, but not the right.

The catch is, I have hundreds of these collections to match up, and the actual CRUD code is different.

I'd like to introduce some shared code where I can pass in both collections, the collection types (as probably generics), some kind of comparer, and some delegates of what operation to perform for CRUD.

If this code actually existed, it may look something like this

```
class Stuff
{
   string Id {get; set;}
   string Name {get; set;}
}

class Junk
{
    string Id {get; set;}
    string ShortName {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<Stuff> myStuff = GetStuff();
IEnumerable<Junk> myJunk = GetJunk();

CrudComparer cc = new CrudComparer<Stuff, Junk>(myStuff, myJunk);
cc.Comparer = (leftObject, rightObject) => {
    leftObject.Name == rightObject.Name
}

cc.CreateOperation = (newObject, rightCollection) => {
    Junk j = new Junk();
    j.Shortname = newObject.Name;
    rightCollection.Add(j);
} 

cc.UpdateOperation = (leftObject, rightObject) => {
    rightObject.Shortname = leftObject.Name;
}

cc.DeleteOperation = (rightCollection, rightObject) => {
    rightCollection.Remove(rightObject);
}

cc.Compare();
```

Has anyone ever seen code that does something like this?  I'd hate to reinvent the wheel if I can grab something already done.

Thanks for any help!
--Michael

Comment: Might want to pose this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @roryap when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat -- noted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got to thinking more about this, and realized what I knew about delgates and generics should be sufficient to solve this problem, so I got in LinqPad and had some fun.  I haven't written any unit tests around this yet, so use at your own risk, but hopefully if you want to use this you understand the underlying concepts.

```
class Blah
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BlahName { get; set;}
}

class Bleh
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BlehName { get; set;}
}

class CrudComparer<TLeft, TRight>
{

    private readonly ICollection<TLeft> _leftCollection;
    private readonly ICollection<TRight> _rightCollection;
    private readonly Comparer _compareOperation;
    private readonly CreateOperation _createOperation;
    private readonly UpdateOperation _updateOperation;
    private readonly DeleteOperation _deleteOperation;

    public delegate bool Comparer(TLeft leftItem, TRight rightItem);
    public delegate void CreateOperation(TLeft leftItem, ICollection<TRight> rightCollection);
    public delegate void UpdateOperation(TLeft leftItem, TRight rightItem);
    public delegate void DeleteOperation(TRight rightItem, ICollection<TRight> rightCollection);

    public CrudComparer(ICollection<TLeft> leftCollection, ICollection<TRight> rightCollection, Comparer compareOperation, CreateOperation createOperation, UpdateOperation updateOperation, DeleteOperation deleteOperation)
    {
        _leftCollection = leftCollection;
        _rightCollection = rightCollection;
        _compareOperation = compareOperation;
        _createOperation = createOperation;
        _updateOperation = updateOperation;
        _deleteOperation = deleteOperation;
    }

    public void Compare()
    {
        foreach (TLeft leftItem in _leftCollection)
        {
            bool foundItem = false;
            foreach (TRight rightItem in _rightCollection)
            {
                if (_compareOperation(leftItem, rightItem))
                {
                    //these equal
                    foundItem = true;
                }
            }

            if (foundItem == false)
            {
                _createOperation(leftItem, _rightCollection);
            }
        }


        List<TRight> itemsToDelete = new List<TRight>();
        foreach (TRight rightItem in _rightCollection)
        {
            bool foundItem = false;

            foreach (TLeft leftItem in _leftCollection)
            {
                if (_compareOperation(leftItem, rightItem))
                {
                    foundItem = true;
                    _updateOperation(leftItem, rightItem);
                    break;          
                }
            }

            if (!foundItem)
            {
                itemsToDelete.Add(rightItem);
            }
        }

        foreach (TRight itemToDelete in itemsToDelete)
        {
            _deleteOperation(itemToDelete, _rightCollection);
        }
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<Blah> blahItems = new List<Blah>();
    blahItems.Add(new Blah() { ID = 1, BlahName = "Blah" });
    blahItems.Add(new Blah() { ID = 2, BlahName = "ABC" });
    blahItems.Add(new Blah() { ID = 34, BlahName = "XYZ" });
    blahItems.Add(new Blah() { ID = 6442, BlahName = "123" });

    List<Bleh> blehItems = new List<Bleh>();
    blehItems.Add(new Bleh() { ID = 2, BlehName = "12345"});
    blehItems.Add(new Bleh() { ID = 6, BlehName = "43232"});
    blehItems.Add(new Bleh() { ID = 77, BlehName = "BlahBlah"});
    blehItems.Add(new Bleh() { ID = 2334, BlehName = "ZYX"});

    CrudComparer<Blah, Bleh>.Comparer compareOperation = (leftObject, rightObject) => 
    { 
        return leftObject.ID == rightObject.ID; 
    };
    CrudComparer<Blah, Bleh>.CreateOperation createOperation = (leftObject, rightCollection) => 
    { 
        rightCollection.Add(new Bleh() { ID = leftObject.ID }); 
    };
    CrudComparer<Blah, Bleh>.UpdateOperation updateOperation = (leftObject, rightObject) =>
    {
        rightObject.BlehName = leftObject.BlahName;
    };
    CrudComparer<Blah, Bleh>.DeleteOperation deleteOperation = (rightObject, rightCollection) =>
    {
        rightCollection.Remove(rightObject);
    };

    CrudComparer<Blah, Bleh> cc = new CrudComparer<Blah, Bleh>(blahItems, blehItems, compareOperation, createOperation, updateOperation, deleteOperation);
    cc.Compare();
}
```